# Make a material-ui icon bolder

Tags: reactjs, icons, material-ui

I want to display a disabled-but-giving-feedback button like in [this answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/131282/5242) using a block icon from [material icons](https://material-ui.com/components/material-icons/#material-icons). It works, however, it'd look much better when the icon was bolder.

Can I make an imported icon look bolder? I guess, modifying the pen width in the SVG would do, but don't know how to do it (especially, whether it's possible "from the outside").

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to set `stroke` and `stroke-width` CSS property on SVG element holding that icon.

For example:

```
stroke: black;
stroke-width: 2;
```

makes your icon black, and two times the line width.

Comment: This also works when you add it as a style variable through the classes/classname property of the icon.

Comment: @RaymondWachaga can you write an example?

Comment: @Raskul, here is an example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-icons-material-ui-dk5811?file=/demo.js